# Trying to subclass Tab in order to make style changes

Tags: tabs, material-design, codenameone

I'm trying to make a material design inspired `Tab` component, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting a bottom border to show up on the selected tab.  I understand that the best way to do this is to override the Tab style in the theme, but there's no way to set just a bottom border there.  I even went so far as to use an `ActionListener` to set the border when the tab is clicked, but then the border only flashes for a moment, as it seems the UIID gets reset immediately after being selected.

I'm looking for an effect similar to the Skype android app, where the current tab is 'underlined' at all times.

[image]

How can I make the border appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a 9 piece border in the style that has a solid or transparent/translucent color and a line on the bottom.

No need to subclass.

Comment: Will the line extend all the way to the corners on the bottom?

Comment: That depends on how you cut it and the source image

Comment: I tried doing this, but nothing showed.  I want the bottom border to show only on the current tab, so I set the border in the 'selected' style, but no dice.

Comment: Do that in the pressed style

Comment: I changed it to the pressed style, and now it appears, but only while I'm actively pressing the tab

Comment: That would be the behavior of the selected style, so you must have changed something in your attempts either by customizing the tabs component in a way that breaks that behavior or the styling is incorrect